# Unknown Shiny Loading Page Error - core dumped?

Tags: r, shiny

I deployed a shiny app to the free shiny server. The URL will load and I will see the "please wait" loading bar. After a while I will eventually an "signal: aborted (core dumped)". The logs for my shiny account show no errors. Indicates everything loaded correctly.

Does any one know what this means? I can't seem to find much online about this error in regards to shiny apps

[image: error]

Comment: Have you tried re-deploying the app?

Comment: we have no idea what your app contains to guess the problem! please make a reproducible example